# Pills sticking together even when using margin - Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, nav-pills

I have these pills that look fine when I'm using full screen but if I minimize the screen they all stack together. I'm having trouble understanding why because I have margin on them. Is there something else you should use for pills to add margin?

Tailwind Playground Link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/DZQUeJAQBf?size=224x720

Comment: What you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: The accepted answer is what I'm trying to achieve. @KrishnaAcharya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that if the text wraps into a newline there is no margin attached because it's kind of the same row but automatically wrapped.

You could use sth. like flex-box to arrange your pills in groups.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/9YtIfBxPRe?size=160x720